How can I switch a TypeScript variable with a union type to a different case?
Consider the following TypeScript program:
interface X {
  type: "x";
}

interface Y {
  type: "y";
}

interface Z {
  type: "z";
}

type U = X | Y | Z;

const u = { type: "x" } as U;

I would now like to conditionally change the value of u.type, however both attempts have their own problems:
if (u.type === "x") {
  // Attempt 1
  u.type = "y"; // error: Type '"y"' is not assignable to type '"x"'.ts(2322)

  // Attempt 2
  u = { type: "y" }; // Cannot assign to 'u' because it is a constant.ts(2588)
}

Is there a way to conditionally update u.type without writing let u?

This is an off-label use of unions. You're not supposed to mutate a value from one union member to another. Answers below are reasonable; I'd say you really want {type: "x" | "y" | "z"} instead of your U type. Does your use case really have only one property? Or are there other properties that need to change along with it? I'd be wary of any code that sidestepped the union discrimination on purpose like this.

One not very pretty workaround to this is to maintain a "wider" interface U that each other interface X, Y, and Z extends. That way you can reassign the type property of a U at any point. Then when you want to narrow the type you can use a type assertion function.
interface U {
    type: "x" | "y" | "z"
}

interface X extends U {
  type: "x";
}

interface Y extends U {
  type: "y";
}

interface Z extends U {
  type: "z";
}

const u = { type: "x" } as U;

const isX = (v: U): v is X => {
    return v.type === "x"
}

// Keep as U and we can reassign type
if (u.type === "x") {
  u.type = "y"; 
}

// Narrow to X and TS will disallow reassignment of type
if (isX(u)) {
  u.type = "y"; // Type '"y"' is not assignable to type '"x"'.(2322)
}


The condition if (u.type === "x") causes TypeScript to recognize that inside the if-block, u is defined as u: X.
The answer by iKingNinja provides a few workarounds, but they don't prevent the type narrowing from happening.
If you want to prevent the type from being narrowed, here are a few ways to do that:


let uType = u.type;  // Note the `let`, won't work with `const`.
if (uType === "x") {
  u.type = "y";      // Still defined as u: U
}



const getType = (u: U) => u.type;
if (getType(u) === "x") {
  u.type = "y";      // Still defined as u: U
}



const hasType = (u: U, type: string) => u.type === type;
if (hasType(u, "x")) {
  u.type = "y";      // Still defined as u: U
}



More ways are possible as long as the if check is not recognizable by TypeScript as a static type check.

You first need to assert the type of u and then change u.type's value.
(u as U).type = "y";
or if you want to assert u as Y you will have to assert it as unknown first because X and Y don't overlap.
(u as unknown as Y).type = "y";
